# Login Not Showing Errors

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this code for a login system:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    $connection = connect($bd_config);

    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    $result = $statement->fetch();
    if ($result !== false) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        @header('Location: main.php');
    }else{
        $errors = '<p>Your data is wrong!</p>';
    }
}
```

And on the frontend I have this:

```
<?php if(!empty($errors)) : ?>
    <div class="errors">
        <ul>
            <?php echo $errors; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So when submitting the form if a field is empty, it should show the error, "Your data is wrong!", but it isn't. I've already changed the ´echo´ for a ´var_dump´, but still, it ain't showing anything...

What is going on?

Comment: Running a SELECT query that returns zero rows is not an error. You just got zero results, so even though you didn't give the correct information, the query succeeded.

Comment: Note also, you should not use SHA for password hashing. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Instead of including the password in the where clause, select the record for that user and then (via password_verify) verify the password in the record matches what the user typed.

Comment: Are those two different pages?  If so, how does `$errors` get from one page to the other?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, they are 2 different pages and... I don't know how to use a variable in other file

Comment: How do you get from the first page to the second?

Comment: For that I'm using a require if the session is set. Like this: if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){header('Location: link.php');} else{require 'login.view.php';}

Answer (score 0):

fetch return false when query fails. Try change your IF to use count($result) < 1

Comment: Welcome to SO, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What do you mean with changing my IF? You mean the "if server request_method == post"?

Comment: Is the same that @AlexHowansky sayed. The query result can be a array with zero rows and it is not boolean value is just a zero rows. You need use if(count($result) < 1) or create a  function to validate the data. If you use PDO, you can look fetch types and use something like PDO::FETCH_COLUMN to return only the id of the user 
[link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) and verify if the result is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only display an error if `fetch()` returns `false`:

```
 $result = $statement->fetch();
 if ($result !== false) {
     // ...
 } else {
     $errors = '<p>Your data is wrong!</p>';
 }
```

This only happens when the query *fails* -- for example, if you're referencing a table that doesn't exist. Performing a `SELECT` that returns zero rows is *not an error*. The query successfully completed, it just didn't find anything. You need to inspect the result set to count the number of rows returned.

Better, use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash the password when saving. Then query with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email` and use [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check the value that was retrieved against the value that was typed.